# Need Form Data as Array - Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am working on creating a single page PHP application and trying to submit the form via ajax .post() rather than the typical form submission that navigates away. Trouble is I can't figure out how to get the array of all the info right so I can pass it into the .post() command.

The code below generates the table, and form pulling all the data from the database, and if I were to wrap it in a form tag it would work as is. You can see the processed version along with some debug code here if you click on Ajax Menu on the side bar: http://tinyurl.com/lq4fe8a

```
<?
include 'db.php';


$i=0;
    foreach($db->query('SELECT * from navmenu') as $row) {
    $rowarray[$i] = array();
    echo ($i % 2)?'<tr class="odd">':'<tr class="even">';

        print_r("<td width=200>" . $row[2] . "</td>");
        print_r("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\""); 
        $row[2] = str_replace(' ', '_', $row[2]);
        print_r("". $row[2] . "[0]\"  value=\"" . $row[0] . "\">");
        print_r("<td><input type=\"textbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[1]\" size=\"75\" value=\"" . $row[3] . "\"></td>");
        //parent selection
        print_r("<td><select id=\"" . $row[2] . "[2]\">");

        if($row[1] == "0"){
            print_r("<option value=\"0\" selected>No Parent</option>");
        }

    foreach($db->query('SELECT * from navmenu') as $option) {
        print_r("<option value=\"" . $option[0] . "\"");
        if($row[1] == $option[0]){
            print_r(" selected");
        }
        print_r(">" . $option[2] ."</option>");
        }
        // end foreach
        print_r("</select></td>");
        print_r("<td><input type=\"textbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[3]\" size=\"5\" value=\"" . $row[4] . "\"></td>");
        // setup status whether active or not
        print_r("<td><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[4]\" value=\"INACTIVE\"> "); //set value so it never passes NULL
            if ($row[3] == "ACTIVE"){
            print_r("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[4]\" value=\"ACTIVE\" checked=\"true\"></td></tr>");
            }
            else{
            print_r("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" . $row[2] . "[4]\" value=\"ACTIVE\"></td></tr>");

            }
    print_r("\n");
    $rowarray[$i]= array("$row[2][0]", "$row[2][1]", "$row[2][2]", "$row[2][3]", "$row[2][4]"); 
    $i++; //increment by one

    }

?>
```

At the bottom where I define $rowarray in the foreach loop, I was trying to add all the info from the form into a single array but instead I end up with this:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'Settings[0]' (length=11)
      1 => string 'Settings[1]' (length=11)
      2 => string 'Settings[2]' (length=11)
      3 => string 'Settings[3]' (length=11)
      4 => string 'Settings[4]' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'Grid_Demo[0]' (length=12)
      1 => string 'Grid_Demo[1]' (length=12)
      2 => string 'Grid_Demo[2]' (length=12)
      3 => string 'Grid_Demo[3]' (length=12)
      4 => string 'Grid_Demo[4]' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string 'TEST[0]' (length=7)
      1 => string 'TEST[1]' (length=7)
      2 => string 'TEST[2]' (length=7)
      3 => string 'TEST[3]' (length=7)
      4 => string 'TEST[4]' (length=7)
```

It is storing the items as strings and not sub arrays, so I can't do something like print_r($rowarray[0][0]) to get the contents. Not sure what I did wrong or where to go from here. For what it is worth, here is the javascript submit code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[id^=formsubmit]").click(function ( event ) {
            $.post("functions.php?do=adminmenu",{
            // Send these values via POST
            <?
                foreach ($rowarray as $index => $option) {
                    foreach ($option as $rowitem => $rowval)
                    {
                    $option = str_replace(' ', '_', $option);
                    print "$index:$('[id^=\'$rowval\']').val(), ";
                    } 
                }
                print "$index:$('#$rowval').val()";
            ?>
            }
            ,function (data) {
                $( ".contentarea2" ).html( data );
            },"html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does the Javascript look like when you view source in the browser? I suspect that the object passed to the `$.post` method for your values is not valid or is not generating the structure you want.

Comment: @Kryten The javascript is below, but right now the larger issue is that $rowarray doesn't have the right info.

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[id^=formsubmit]").click(function ( event ) {
    $.post("functions.php?do=adminmenu",{
    // Send these values via POST
    0:$('[id^=\'Array\']').val(), 1:$('[id^=\'Array\']').val(), 2:$('[id^=\'Array\']').val(), 3:$('[id^=\'Array\']').val(), 4:$('[id^=\'Array\']').val(), 5:$('[id^=\'Array\']').val(), 6:$('[id^=\'Array\']').val(), 6:$('#Array').val() }
    ,function (data) {
    $( ".contentarea2" ).html( data );
    },"html");
    });
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was forgetting to store them as $key => $value pairs. For at least the first part of the problem it was solved by doing this:

```
$rowarray[$row[0]]= array("id" => "$row[0]", "parentid" => "$row[1]", "name" => "$row[2]", "url" => "$row[3]", "sortorder" => "$row[4]", "status" => "$row[5]", "tooltip" => "$row[6]");
```

Which then stored it like this:

```
array
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'parentid' => string '0' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Settings' (length=8)
      'url' => string 'settings.php' (length=12)
      'sortorder' => string '0' (length=1)
      'status' => string 'INACTIVE' (length=8)
      'tooltip' => string 'tooltip' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'parentid' => string '0' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Grid_Demo' (length=9)
      'url' => string 'grid.php' (length=8)
      'sortorder' => string '100' (length=3)
      'status' => string 'INACTIVE' (length=8)
      'tooltip' => string '' (length=0)
```